# Why SVG element definition in w3c always has full presentation attributes?

Tags: svg, w3c

Recently, i have to dig into w3c specification, it's really mess :( while i reading specifications, i wonder Why SVG element definition in w3c always has full presentation attributes?

for example in 'mask' element definition

from: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/masking.html#MaskElement

```
    Attributes:

conditional processing attributes — ‘requiredFeatures’, ‘requiredExtensions’, ‘systemLanguage’
core attributes — ‘id’, ‘xml:base’, ‘xml:lang’, ‘xml:space’
presentation attributes — ‘alignment-baseline’, ‘baseline-shift’, ‘clip’, ‘clip-path’, ‘clip-rule’, ‘color’, ‘color-interpolation’, ‘color-interpolation-filters’, ‘color-profile’, ‘color-rendering’, ‘cursor’, ‘direction’, ‘display’, ‘dominant-baseline’, ‘enable-background’, ‘fill’, ‘fill-opacity’, ‘fill-rule’, ‘filter’, ‘flood-color’, ‘flood-opacity’, ‘font-family’, ‘font-size’, ‘font-size-adjust’, ‘font-stretch’, ‘font-style’, ‘font-variant’, ‘font-weight’, ‘glyph-orientation-horizontal’, ‘glyph-orientation-vertical’, ‘image-rendering’, ‘kerning’, ‘letter-spacing’, ‘lighting-color’, ‘marker-end’, ‘marker-mid’, ‘marker-start’, ‘mask’, ‘opacity’, ‘overflow’, ‘pointer-events’, ‘shape-rendering’, ‘stop-color’, ‘stop-opacity’, ‘stroke’, ‘stroke-dasharray’, ‘stroke-dashoffset’, ‘stroke-linecap’, ‘stroke-linejoin’, ‘stroke-miterlimit’, ‘stroke-opacity’, ‘stroke-width’, ‘text-anchor’, ‘text-decoration’, ‘text-rendering’, ‘unicode-bidi’, ‘visibility’, ‘word-spacing’, ‘writing-mode’
‘class’
‘style’
‘externalResourcesRequired’
‘x’
‘y’
‘width’
‘height’
‘maskUnits’
‘maskContentUnits’
```

**presentation attributes** always has full attributes but there are some of them is active with 'mask' element! Why does w3c just show active attribute?

======================================================================

maybe question is not clear, sorry for that, my English is really bad :(

one more example for my question is ‘flood-color’ attribute

from: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/filters.html#FloodColorProperty

```
‘flood-color’
Value:      currentColor |
<color> [<icccolor>] |
inherit
Initial:    black
Applies to:     ‘feFlood’ elements
Inherited:      no
Percentages:    N/A
Media:      visual
Animatable:     yes
```

you can see that: "**Applies to:    ‘feFlood’ elements**" but when you see all attributes of 'mask' element above you also see ‘flood-color’ in there. So i wonder is ‘flood-color’ attribute active with 'mask' element or only active with 'feFlood' element? If not active with 'mask' why w3c list it in attributes of 'mask' element?

Sorry again for my English. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RobertLongson i just add one more question, sorry for my unclear question! Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The w3c wrote it this way because they thought it would be easier for implementers if all presentation attributes could be put on all elements regardless of whether they had any effect.

Comment: It's also to mimic how css works, e.g you can set `opacity` on a <link> element, even if it won't have any visual effect. You can inspect the computed style using DOM calls however.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but it's a little bit difficult to know (or list) what attributes are active for what elements! anw, thank you!